# I have a problem with compiz, openGL and everything dissapeared, no icons no nothing

Tags: unity, compiz, icons, opengl

Hi recently I tried to make my desktop to look like a cube but when I opened COMPIZ  and I switch off OPENGL and maybe as well COMPOSITE I am not sure about the second one and everything dissapear what can I do? When I enter as a GUEST everything is ok but when I enter with my profile it does not show the icons, the bar on the top of the desktop with the sound, wi-fi, time, etc. but fromthe keybord i can open my files and home folder i can listen to music watch movie even download torrents  what to do please?

Answer (score 0):

Press "ctrl + alt + T" to open a terminal and type "compiz-config". You should now fix the problem from here in options, by restoring default settings of the profile you are using. Does it work?